# Override observable emissions with another observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Suppose that I have 2 observables that frequently emit values at similar times: `default$` and `override$`. Whenever `default$` emits, I want to wait 50ms to see if `override$` also emits. If `override$` emits within the 50ms, I want to use the value from `override$`. Otherwise, I want to use the value from `default$`.

I set up the test case below to try things out:

```js
const default$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(map(() => 'default'), take(10));
const override$ = timer(49, 2000).pipe(map(() => 'override'), take(5));
```

I think I should be able to use `switchMap()` to accomplish this, but I can't figure out how.

My coworker suggested using `debounceTime()`, but this ignores the "preferential treatment" that I want to assign to the `override$` observable:

```js
const result = merge(default$, override$).pipe(debounceTime(50)).subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Does anyone know how I might go about doing this? Even if `default$` never emits, I still want to take action on emission of `override$`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem right, I would proceed like this.

Everything starts with `default$` emitting a value.

When `default$` emits a value, we switch (`switchMap`) to a new stream which is the merge of 2 streams:

- a stream that notifies the value emitted by `default$` with a delay of 500 ms; such stream will not emit anything is `override$` emits first
- a stream which emits what `override$` emits

We want also to make sure that we do not re-subscribe to `override$` any time we `switchMap` because `default$` has notified something, and so we turn `override$` into an hot Observable.

So the code would look like this

```
// create an hot Observable from override
const overrideHot = new Subject<any>();
override$.subscribe(overrideHot);

const finalObs = default$.pipe(
  switchMap((val) =>
    merge(
      of(val).pipe(
        delay(500),
        tap((val) =>
        // do what has to be done when you have to act on default$
          console.log('Default notified and override did not == - val ' + val)
        ),
        takeUntil(overrideHot)
      ),
      overrideHot.pipe(
        // do what has to be done when you have to act on override$
        tap((val) => console.log('Override notified - val ' + val))
      )
    )
  )
);

finalObs.subscribe();
```

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zlaxtg?file=index.ts) shows your example emitting 10 outputs, alternating between "override" and "default" (and then continuing with additional values notified by `override$` after `default$` has stopped emitting).

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT**
If you want to `override$` to notify even if `default$` has not started, you have to complicate a bit the solution.

The idea is that upstream (i.e. where all notifications come from) is not just `default$`, but is a `merge` of `default$` and a stream that notifies immediately a non relevant value. A stream that notifies immediately can be built with the `of` function.

The non relevant value is then filtered out (via `filter` operator) downstream, since it is useful just to kick start the process.

So the final result should look like this

```
const finalObs = merge(defaultDelayed$, of(null)).pipe(
  switchMap((val) =>
    merge(
      of(val).pipe(
        filter((val) => val != null),
        delay(500),
        tap((val) =>
          console.log('Default notified and override did not == - val ' + val)
        ),
        takeUntil(overrideHot)
      ),
      overrideHot.pipe(
        tap((val) => console.log('Override notified - val ' + val))
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Here the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uxmpvv?file=index.ts) with the updated code.

Comment: This is so close.  The only case it doesn't cover is the case when `default$` never emits (or doesn't emit until after many `override$` emissions).

Answer (score 0):

Whould something like that match what you want ?

```
import { race, map, defer, timer, take, delay } from 'rxjs';

const default$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  map(() => 'default'),
  take(10)
);
const override$ = timer(49, 2000).pipe(
  map(() => 'override'),
  take(5)
);

race(
  defer(() => default$.pipe(delay(50))),
  defer(() => override$)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Closer!  I had tried `race()`, but the problem there is that it unsubscribes from `default$`   when `override$` emits.  Your solution produces 5 outputs of "override"; whereas, I want 10 outputs, alternating between "override" and "default"

Answer (score 0):

The `race` operator will use the first observable to emit and ignore the rest.  So, you could set up an observable that emits your `default` value after 50ms and race that against the `override$`:

```js
const value$ = default$.pipe(
  switchMap(a => race(override$, of(a).pipe(delay(50))))
);
```

Comment: This has the downside of requiring for `default$` to emit.

Comment: I thought that was the behavior he wanted!

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler is right, I want to use the value from `$override` even if there was no emission from `$default`.  I will clarify this in the question